# Don't rotate subviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rotation

When i used this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:    (NSTimeInterval)duration {

  if ((toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
    LeftLVC* vc = [[LeftLVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftLVC" bundle:nil];      
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];     
  }
}
```

subviews rotate. In my project subviews must stay fixed portrait.

Comment: If you don't want to rotate the view `return false`

Comment: You didn't understand me. I use this code on main view so subviews autorotate.

Comment: use same code in sub views also..

Comment: "Subviews always must stay portrait."

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is used to specify the supported orientation. If you want to support only the portrait mode only then :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);  
}
```

above method is deprecated in iOS 6.0. Override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods instead.
For detail read [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a).

`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins rotating. Here this method will be called when you move the orientation from landscape to portrait.